# How to specify a separate theme for one specific panel page

Tags: panels, theming

Is there a way in Panels 3 (or an add-on that integrates into the Panels UI) that lets you specify a different sub-theme to use on a given panel page?

I've looked through the UI for both the regular Panel pages, as well as in the Panels Everywhere site template -- but can't find any mention of theme selection.

I know the ThemeKey module would be the traditional recommended solution here, but I don't want to add another heavyweight module for one single page on the site. And would prefer not to write a custom module with a hook_init() that changes the theme.

My understanding is that Panels handles layout -- not theme selection -- but there seems like no reason Panels couldn't also provide the ability to specify which theme to load, in addition to the layout to display.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to theme just the panel or the whole page including header etc?

Comment: I'm looking to switch the Drupal theme from the site's main theme to a sub-theme for one single panel page.  The sub-theme contains style changes for page wrapper, header, footer etc -- so yes, the whole page.

Comment: themekey is your solution.  Otherwise this is a feature request for Panels, and is off-topic here.